# Can I use the HITS Link Analysis Algorithm in NetworkX Python Library on a undirected weighted graph?

Tags: python, networkx, pagerank

I want to know if I  can use the HITS link analysis algorithm in NetworkX on an undirected weighted graph. Following which I wish to sort in descending order the hub score of the nodes in the graph.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you read the [docstring](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/link_analysis/hits_alg.html#hits) for the function?

> ```
> The HITS algorithm was designed for directed graphs but this
> algorithm does not check if the input graph is directed and will
> execute on undirected graphs.
> ```

So yes, you *can* use it.

Comment: What if the graph has weighted edges?. In the NetworkX implementation of PageRank you can specify the attribute for weights.

Comment: Its not mentioned in the documentation. networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.hits_alg.hits.html

Comment: Read the source code in the link I provided. Set the `"weight"` attribute on edges of your graph. And perhaps you can submit a pull request to clarify the documentation.

Comment: So i can pass a undirected weighted graph G like this  h,a=nx.hits(G) and it will work?